# For SSRS in Visual Studio 2008, how can I make a variable accept multiple values as well as a single value?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, variables, reporting-services

I'm making a report with Visual Studio 2008, pulling the info from a table in a database. Let's say I just want to show the `Type` of employee (which is represented by an `int`, say 1-10) and their `Name`. Then my dataset would be this query:

```
SELECT Type, Name
FROM Employees
WHERE Type = @Type
```

This is SSRS, so I do not need to declare or set the variable (correct me if I'm wrong). When I run the report, it will give me an option to type in an `int` for the `Type` and it will create the corresponding report. My question is how can I set it so that I can type `1,2,3` in for the `Type` so that I get a report with those types of employees? So having the `int` variable be able to accept a list of `ints` or just one `int`. Essentially the "resulting query" from that example would look like this:

```
SELECT Type, Name
FROM Employees
WHERE Type = 1 AND Type = 2 AND Type = 3
```

Comment: The total no. of int values coming as parameter values are fixed or they may increase or decrease?

Comment: Good to know that you were able to find the solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the left side in the Report Data window under the Parameters folder, right click the variable, hit Parameter Properties, then check 'Allow Multiple Values' and select the correct datatype in the dropdown. I'm not sure why it decides to make a dropdown when you run the report, and you have to enter the values each on their own line instead of separated by commas, but it seems to work fine. Then just change the `WHERE` clause in your dataset from `WHERE Type = @Type` to `WHERE Type IN (@Type)`. I don't know if the parentheses are necessary.

Also if you create a separate dataset that will present certain values you can have those show up instead of having to type them out. For example, create a dataset that contains this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Type
FROM Employees
ORDER BY Type
```

This will create a list of distinct values for type that you can check/uncheck. You can make it more complex obviously as well.